# How do I add input numbers eliminating the ones duplicated?

Tags: java, input, sum

For example my input numbers are: 10 10 and 15. The second input will be ignored since it is already duplicated. So the sum would be 10+15 - 25. How do I do this?

```
public class MP2A {

    public static Scanner objScan = new Scanner (System.in);
    public static void main (String []args)
    {
        double [] dNum = new double[3];

        System.out.println("Input values for your array");
        for (int iCtr=0; iCtr<dNum.length; iCtr++) {
           dNum[iCtr] = objScan.nextDouble();
        }

        double sum = 0;
        for (int iCtr=0; iCtr<dNum.length; iCtr++) {
            for (int iCtr2=0; iCtr2<dNum.length-1; iCtr2++) {
                if (dNum[iCtr2] == dNum[iCtr]) {
                   continue;
                }  
            } 
            sum+=dNum[iCtr];
        }     
        System.out.println(sum);

    }     
}
```

I came up with the program above, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Check if the current number is equal to to the previous number. If so, don't print it.

Comment: The naive solution would be just keep track of everything you are adding (eg: using a `HashSet`) - if it hasn't been added before, add it to the accumulator.

Comment: I have tried doing that one. But the requirement of the program is not to print. I have to add the input numbers but ignoring the ones duplicated. I tried using if statements. It determines the duplicate but when I try to compute for the sum, everything is still added.

Comment: Your inner loop does nothing. Think about it.

Comment: Alright. I am going to try @Aasmund Eldhuset suggestion. Thank you very much.

Comment: A Set is the quickest solution. Sorting is an alternative if you are allowed to do that.

Answer (score 4):

You should check out the [`HashSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) class. You can put as many numbers as you like into a `HashSet`, but even if the same number is inserted several times, the `HashSet` will only contain one occurrence of each unique number.

Edit: If you are not allowed to use `HashSet`, you can do it this way: Use an `ArrayList<int>` (or a large `int[]` if you're not allowed to use `ArrayList` either) to keep track of the numbers that have been added. For each new number, check if the number already exists in the list, and only add it to the list (and to the sum) if it's not already there.

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot use the HashSet class yet since it is not yet discussed in our lecture. Any more suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Think how you would solve the problem with pencil and paper:

> 1. Get the next number.
> 2. Have we seen this number before?
> 3. If we have then go back to step 1.
> 4. If not then add the number to the list of numbers we've already seen.
> 5. Add the number to the total.
> 6. Go back to step 1.

Now see how your code matches that simple algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Add all the inputs into a `Set` and then iterate over the `Set` elements for the sum.

Answer (score 0):

Add input numbers to your array only if it doesn't already contain it. This is assuming that you haven't been introduced to [`java.util.List`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) yet (you've already mentioned that you don't know about Sets).

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MP2A {

    public static Scanner objScan = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] dNum = new double[3];

        System.out.println("Input values for your array");
        for (int i = 0; i < dNum.length; i++) {
            double num = objScan.nextDouble();
            if (contains(dNum, num) == false) {
                dNum[i] = num;
            }
        }
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < dNum.length; i++) {
            sum += dNum[i];
        }
        System.out.println(sum);

    }

    public static boolean contains(double[] d, double num) {
        for (int i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
            if (d[i] == num) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```